# Net::Bluetooth does not discover devices

Tags: linux, perl, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to connect to my `LegoBoost` under `Perl` on `Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4`. It is a Low Energy Bluetooth (BLE) device. I can discover and connect to it using `gatttool` and `hci*` utilities, but I have no luck with Perl. I tried the following code:

```
use Net::Bluetooth;
use Data::Dumper;

print "Get remote devices...\n";
my $rDevice = get_remote_devices();
print Dumper $rDevice;

my $addr = "00:16:53:A5:3E:50";
print "SDP search...\n";
my @spd = sdp_search($addr, "", ""); # LegoBoost
print Dumper \@spd;
```

returns `undef` and `[undef]`. I even tried as root, but no luck.

I also tried to connect to this device:

```
print "Connect to device...\n";
my $obj = Net::Bluetooth->newsocket("RFCOMM");
defined($obj) or die "socket error $!\n";
print "Socket got ", Dumper $obj;
system 'lsof', '-p', $$;

my $port = 14;
if($obj->connect($addr, $port) != 0) { die "connect error: $!\n";}
print "Connected...\n";
sleep 5;

#### create a Perl filehandle for reading and writing
my $fd = $obj->perlfh();
print Dumper $fd;
close $fd or die;
```

Output:

```
Connect to device...
Socket got $VAR1 = bless( {
                 'PROTO' => 'RFCOMM',
                 'SOCK_FD' => 4
               }, 'Net::Bluetooth' );
connect error: Host is down
```

Any idea is appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Net::Bluetooth` is for normal bluetooth devices, not for BLE. I read the source of the Perl package `Net-Bluetooth-0.41`. The module's `get_remote_devices` sub is defined in `Bluetooth.c` as a C function. It calls `hci_get_route` (in `libbluetooth.so`) at first then calls `hci_inquiry`, which inquires the bluetooth devices, but not the BLE devices. :(